# Maven - package graphstream does not exist

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I've added a 'graphstream' dependency to my pom.xml file in a maven project, like so:

```xml
<dependency>
     <artifactId>gs-core</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
     <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I've tried to import 'graphstream' to my java file:

```java
import org.graphstream.*;
```

But when I'm running `mvn install`
I'm getting the following error

**package org.graphstream does not exist**

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the [source code](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-core/tree/dev/src/org/graphstream): there is no package `org.graphstream` really. There is a folder `org/graphstream` that contains other folders. You may use `import org.graphstream.graph.*;` as this is a real package. You probably want to recursively import everything, but it's not how Java works. I give you a quote from [this conversation](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2046424/importing-a-package-recursively-with-subpackages):

> There aren't really "sub-packages." The JLS actually uses that term,
> but I don't know why. There's no real hierarchy, other than the one on
> the filesystem and the logical one implied by the names. As far as
> Java is concerned, the packages have no relation to each other.

Here is my dummy code how imports should look in your project:

```
import org.graphstream.graph.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Import works: %s", Graph.class);
    }
}
```

I hope it answers your question. I've also created a [github repo](https://github.com/aistomin/graphstream-test) with my sandbox. Just please check out the code and run `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.test.Test"` in the project's root. If it doesn't work, please show me the output.

Comment: thanks! it's helped me partly. 
now the 'mvn install' is successful but I don't think the import is working.
I've tried to run your dummy code' and I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by 
 `ClassNotFoundException` for the class Graph.

Comment: @KfirEttinger that's strange. I've created a Github repo with my code, that works fine for me (I've updated the answer, you'll find the link here). I've tested it with Java 15 and Maven 3.8.3. Could you checkout the code please?

Comment: strange indeed. I've cloned your project and it is working perfectly. I'll use your code to try to understand what went wrong with my project. thanks a lot!

Comment: the good news are that at least it's not something global in your system, but just something is missing in your code, so you can slowly comparing figure out where the problem is :) I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted :) Thanks.